# Python TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

Tags: python, list

I am getting `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object` when I am trying to search through a list. and when I return a boolean and the index value of the item I am searching for.

```
def name_ser(name):
    found = False
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if names[i] == name:
            found = True
            return found, names.index(name)
        else:
            found = False
            return found,None


def main_menu():
    print('Welcome!\nPlease Choose from the following options...')
    print('1: Create an account\n2: Login ')
    opt = int(input('Enter Your Choice: '))
    if opt == 1:
        name_search = input('Enter Name... ')
        found, _ = name_ser(name_search)
        if found == True:
            print("Account Already excites!")
        elif found == False & len(names) == 0:
            acc_creation(name_search)
            print('Account created!')
```

error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darkmbs/VS-Code/FirstPythonProject/accounts.py", line 100, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "/Users/darkmbs/VS-Code/FirstPythonProject/accounts.py", line 77, in main_menu
    found, _ = name_ser(name_search)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: `found, _ = name_ser(name_search)` needs `name_ser(...)` result to be an iterable, you can update `return found` with `return found, None`, for example.

Comment: `name_ser()` sometimes returns two values, sometimes only one value.  You cannot split the return value into two variables (`found` and `_`) when there's only one return value!

Comment: If you find the name, just return the index. If the name isn't found, return `None` (or, if `None` is a valid name for whatever reason, raise an exception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name_ser` can return 3 different objects.

```
def name_ser(name):
    found = False
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if names[i] == name:
            found = True
            return found, names.index(name)     <== returns 2-tuple
        else:                                   <== if name[0] doesn't match,
            found = False                           executes immediately
            return found                        <== returns boolean
                                                <== if names is empty, returns None
```

You need a consistent return type. But really, this function shouldn't exist at all. Its trying to return the index of `name` in `names`, or `False`. `str.find` just pretty much just that.

```
def main_menu():
    print('Welcome!\nPlease Choose from the following options...')
    print('1: Create an account\n2: Login ')
    opt = int(input('Enter Your Choice: '))
    if opt == 1:
        name_search = input('Enter Name... ')
        if name_search in names:
            print("Account Already exists!")
        else:
            acc_creation(name_search)
            print('Account created!')
```

I also removed the check for `name_ser` being empty before adding an account. I think it would be strange if only 1 person could create an account.

Comment: i got this error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: @DarkMbs - got wrong variable name. Should be `found = names.find(name_search)` and the `name_ser` function should be deleted entirely.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: Oops, you're right. I didn't run the code. LOL my bad. Gotta remember not to answer questions where the poster hasn't made a good test case. You need to do `names.index(name_search)` and since that can raise an exception, either test first or catch it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the earlier comments, you cannot return both one or two values. My recommendation is to return the index of the name. Or if it is not found, return the value `-1`.

```py
def name_ser(name):
    # Check if element is in list
    if name in names:
        # Return index of element
        return names.index(name)
    else:
        # Name was not found in the list
        return -1

def main_menu():
    print('Welcome!\nPlease Choose from the following options...')
    print('1: Create an account\n2: Login ')

    opt = int(input('Enter Your Choice: '))

    # Create account
    if opt == 1:
        name_search = input('Enter Name... ')
        found = name_ser(name_search)

        if found >= 0:
            print("Account Already exists!")

        elif found == -1 & len(names) == 0:
            acc_creation(name_search)
            print('Account created!')
    
    # Login to Account
    if opt == 2:
        # Update to use index instead of boolean
```

Comment: I really don't understand for some reason the `acc_creation(name_search)` is not being called it was work fine a min ago I closed the IDE and opened it again now it's not working. not even giving any errors

Comment: Once again, this solved the original issue. There is no possible way to fix a method that we have no view of. If you are concerned if a method is being called, you can always use a debugger or just simply use `print` to check where something is breaking